# LoginView logout button not linking

Tags: hyperlink, umbraco, logout, loginview

I use a LoginView control for my umbraco website.
I can login but then the Logout button has not link, it just displays 'Logout' text without a possibility to click it.

This is my code:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="lwLogin" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login ID="lwLoginPanel" CssClass="panel-fieldset" UserNameLabelText="Email Address:" TitleText="" TitleTextStyle-CssClass="h3" runat="server">
            </asp:Login>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:LoginName
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="logStatus" runat="server" />
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the LoggedInTemplate you have an uncompleted control definition:

```
<LoggedInTemplate>
        **<asp:LoginName**
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="logStatus" runat="server" />
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

That might cause the issue.
You can also add extra attribrutes to the LoginStatus control:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="lgnStatus" runat="server" LogoutText="uitloggen" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="/loginpage"  />
```